# how to remove an extra series in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

This my code, it did not show any error in here, but the chart always shows a extra series4 here, I can not move, i checked my data, there is no error here two, so i really don't understand
here is the data

```
LIBGEO  Paris   Marseille   Lyon    Toulouse    Nice    Bordeaux    Strasbourg  Nantes  Montpellier Lille   Aix-en-Provence Rennes  Grenoble    Saint-?tienne   Boulogne-Billancourt
smallsize   107676  19207   16122   11767   10771   8081    7043    6915    6799    6422    5372    4764    4472    4261    4234
middlesize  2926    548 558 444 189 222 223 275 202 205 210 171 102 146 226
largesize   180 20  29  28  9   13  12  14  12  12  4   7   13  5   14
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'The number of Different size of company'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Number of company'
      },
      type: 'logarithmic'
    },
    series: []
  };


  $.get('numenterprise.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
      var items = line.split(',');

      // header line containes categories
      if (lineNo == 0) {
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });
      }

      // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
      else {
        var series = {
          data: []
        };
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo == 0) {
            series.name = item;
          } else {
            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
          }
        });

        options.series.push(series);

      }

    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });


});
```

how to remove the Series 4, i do not know how did it appear!!! please help

Comment: Check the csv file itself for a last empty line. That happen on csv falie made from Excel and some other spreadsheet software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is probably caused by empty line at the end of your csv file.
If you can not edit the csv file, you can programmatically remove last series from `options.series` array (before creating the chart):

```
options.series.splice(-1,1);
```